# HTTP 403 – Forbidden - Tomcat - Debian9 - Flowable

Tags: debian, tomcat

I'm facing an issue that's breaking my head, I already had a proof of concept of this setup and now it's not working OLE!

So, I have a small script that kindof setups the server that looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install tmux -y
sudo apt-get install unzip -y
wget https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/releases/download/flowable-6.5.0/flowable-6.5.0.zip
unzip flowable-6.5.0.zip
sudo apt install default-jdk -y
sudo groupadd tomcat
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
wget https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.31/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.31.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /opt/tomcat
sudo tar xzvf apache-tomcat-9.0.31.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
sudo cp flowable-6.5.0/wars/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
cd /opt/tomcat
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
sudo chmod -R g+r conf
sudo chmod g+x conf
sudo chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
echo '[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service > /dev/null
sudo apt-get install ufw -y
sudo ufw allow 8080
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw enable
```

Now after this is done I hit `y` that will enable UFW, next to that I open this `server.xml`
and smash keyboard with..

```
sudo vim /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

and write

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" 
            autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Alias>hereGoesMyIPAddress</Alias>
</Host>
```

I also add an user for the tomcat interface running `sudo vim /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and adding

```
<tomcat-users . . .>
    <user username="admin" password="VeryStrongPasswordLolILeftClearTextPasswordBeforeEdit" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

AT LAST, I comment out 2 files that basically restrict connections from anywhere..

```
sudo vim /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
sudo vim /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

Commenting this nightmarish piece of characters..

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
</Context>
```

Lastly I SMASH with all my strength `sudo systemctl restart tomcat` but when I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/flowable-idm it just throws out a `HTTP 403 – Forbidden`

Can anyone point me out WHAT AM I DOING WRONG, I did this the first time step by step manually without using a script and it worked and did it manually over and over again without being able to access the flowable .war files I downloaded into tomcat webapps/ , I'm losing my mind please assist me thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: The `flowable-idm` web application probably needs some setup before you are given access to it. Look into the logs (in your case `/opt/tomcat/logs`). Note that you could more easily install Tomcat9 using the `tomcat9` package from [stretch-backports](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/tomcat9).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll tinker about the "somet setup before getting access to it", look at the ```opt/tomcat/logs``` and setup a new instance with the ```skretch-backports``` package. I'll report back ASAP :D